# How to migrate with south when using 'through' for a ManyToMany field?

Tags: python, django, django-south

I want to change a ManyToMany field in a django app.

I have the following models:

```
class A:
    ...

class B:
    as = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

and I want:

```
class A:
    ...

class C:
     a = models.ForeignKey(A)
     b = models.ForeignKey("B")
     extra_data = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class B:
    as = models.ManyToManyField(A, through=C)
```

I am using south for db migrations. Unfortunately, in this case, south propse to delete the existing `app_b_a` table and to recreate a new `app_c`.

Is there a way to say to south not to recreate the m2m table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try to do it the following way:

1. Add the `C` model but do **not** add any extra data fields to it yet. Just set the 2 FK's to the linked models, so that it's schema is effectively identical to the default m2m table, except table name.
2. Run `schemamigration --auto` for your app.
3. To effectively "delete" the existing table and "create" the new one, without moving data, just delete all the generated migration code from `forwards`/`backwards` methods and add:
   **forwards:** `db.rename_table('yourappname_m2mtablename', 'yourappname_c')`
   **backwards:** `db.rename_table('yourappname_c', 'yourappname_m2mtablename')`
4. Leave the "frozen" models dict as it is!
5. Now you can extend your `C` model and generate a new schemamigration for it.

Comment: Works ok if the name of the fk fields in the new model correspond to the corresponding model. Thanks

Comment: If your real database table has column name like foo_id, make your field name in the "C" model be foo.

Answer (score 2):

Just had to do this myself recently. It's actually fairly easy.

First, add the new through model to your code, but *don't* specify it as the `through` parameter to your `ManyToManyField` yet. Create an auto schemamigration, which will create the new table for you.

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration --auto yourapp
```

Second, create a datamigration:

```
$ python manage.py datamigration yourapp name_of_migration
```

In your forwards migration:

```
for b in orm.B.objects.all():
    for a in b.as.all():
        orm.C.objects.create(a=a, b=b)
```

In your backwards migration:

```
for c in orm.C.objects.all():
    c.b.as.add(a)
```

Finally, add the `through` parameter to your `ManyToManyField`, and generate another auto schemamigration:

```
$ python manage.py schemamigration --auto yourapp
```

Comment: It works ok. Thanks for this tip. I could accept this one but I prefer Beres answer which saves 1 data migration and doesn't require any code to be written.

Comment: What is add(a) in backwards migration? a is not declared there.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to specify the db_table parameter for C as 'app_b_a'. But not sure that would work.